# Correct quotes in query

Tags: android

I've tried a lot of combinations to quote the OR-part, but nothing worked so far.

I would be very happy if someone could tell me the right syntax for this.

```
mCursor = mDb.query(true, SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
          KEY_NAME, KEY_PLACE, KEY_INFO}, 
          KEY_INFO + " like '%" + inputText + "%'" + OR KEY_PLACE + " like '%" + inputText + "%'",
null, null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Rooms and descriptions for it.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the `query` method as it is meant to be? It has the where string and the where args as arguments. Try something like:

```
mCursor = mDb.query(true, SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
          KEY_NAME, KEY_PLACE, KEY_INFO}, 
          KEY_INFO + " like '%?%' OR " + KEY_PLACE + " like '%?%'",
          new String [] {inputText, inputText}, null, null, null);
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. But your code didn't work even with one query. So, I changed it to 'KEY_INFO + " like ?", new String [] {"%"+inputText+"%"}' ... and now, after adding the second query with "OR" 'KEY_INFO + " like ? OR" + KEY_NAME + " like ?"' I've got this error 'sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = near "ORname": syntax error'

Comment: I've got it this way: KEY_NAME + " LIKE" + "'%" + inputText + "%' OR " + KEY_PLACE + " LIKE" + "'%" + inputText + ...

Comment: I have seen the small mistake in the code directly ;-) but the version with %?% didn't work for me. Don't know why.